# Can I specify a timeout for a GCP ai-platform training job?

Tags: google-cloud-automl, gcp-ai-platform-training

I recently submitted a training job with a command that looked like:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training foo --region us-west2 --master-image-uri us.gcr.io/bar:latest -- baz qux
```

(more on how this command works here: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-jobs)

There was a bug in my code which cause the job to just keep running, rather than terminate.  Two weeks and $61 later, I discovered my error and cancelled the job.  I want to make sure I don't make that kind of mistake again.

I'm considering using the `timeout` command within the training container to kill the process if it takes too long (typical runtime is about 2 or 3 hours), but rather than trust the container to kill itself, I would prefer to configure GCP to kill it externally.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you could write a small script that runs your command and then sleeps the time you want until running a [cancel job command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/jobs/cancel).

As a timeout definition is not available in AI Platform training service, I took the liberty to open a Public Issue with a Feature Request to record the lack of this command. You can track the PI progress [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/147084050).

Comment: I had read the docs and not found it, but I wasn't confident enough to be sure I wasn't overlooking something under a different name that applied to a wider range of their products.  I'll keep an eye on the PI, thanks for doing that.  I'm gonna let it soak for a bit, just in case an answer emerges, but I'll circle back and mark this as the answer in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Except the script mentioned above, you can also try:

- TimeOut Keras callback, or timeout= Optuna param (depending on which library you actually use)
- Cron-triggered Lambda (Cloud Function)